# Objective C: Segue which slides to bottom and unhides new ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I'm just starting to use `Storyboards` and want to write a custom `Segue` Class for a Transistion.

**Transistion**: I have a current `ViewController A` and when I initialize `ViewController B`, `ViewController A` slides out to the bottom and `ViewController B` appears behind `ViewController A`. With `nib` files, I would simply but both ViewController into one Container, but I want to achieve the same within the `InterfaceBuilder`

**Steps**

1. Create `ViewController B`
2. Place `ViewController B` behind `ViewController A`
3. Move `ViewController A` out of the bottom
4. Show `ViewController B`

What I've tried so far is this

```
- (void)perform
{

    //#1
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

   //#2
   // [sourceViewController.view insertSubview:destinationViewController.view aboveSubview:sourceViewController.view] ;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         //#3
                         sourceViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, sourceViewController.view.layer.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //#4
                          [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
                     }
     ];

}
```

My problem is #2: How can i get the new ViewController "behind" the current one? and only animate one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore ECSlidingViewController @  https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController . We had the similar requirement as yours, we used this MIT license class.

Comment: sorry, the picture was misleading. I just updated the question, but very nuce library indeed!